# awk: Increment number with leading zeroes

Tags: regex, sed, awk

I've gone through many awk questions here on SO, but still can not create one for my purpose.

I have a file like such:

```
Project Name
Version 1.0
Revision 0059
```

How do I increment 0059 to 0060 while keeping the rest the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

```
$ awk '$1=="Revision"{$2=sprintf("%04d",$2+1);}1' file
Project Name
Version 1.0
Revision 0060
```

Comment: Yes! I didn't know you could assign values to $ variables. But I don't understand what the 1 at the end does.

Comment: 1 at the end means to print every line of the file.

Comment: any non zero number will work, because awk prints a line by default, if true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sed -rne '/^Revision/s/Revision ([0-9]+)/\1/gp' temp.txt | awk '{printf("%04d\n",$0+1)}'
```